# Write line with timestamp+message to file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to create a logfile that adds every time an error occurs a new line to a textfile log.txt. I am pretty new to python, so maybe I miss something...but everytime an error occurs, the log.txt is overwritten and only the current error message is displayed although the error message is different every time (due to timestamp) and I added a \n.

Thats my code so far:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import datetime
```

try:
    path = sys.argv[1]

`ts = time.time()
sttime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S - ')

#some more things but nothing else of interest for here

except:
    error = "ERROR! No file 'bla' found!"
    log = 'log.txt'
    logfile = file(log, "w")
    logfile.write(sttime + error + '\n')
    logfile.close()
    sys.exit(0)`

Maybe you can help me out here. Do I need a loop somewhere? I tried to create an empty string (error = "") that adds the error message to log.txt with += each time an error occurs, but that didn't work at all :-/

Thank you!

Comment: Open the file with `"a"` as the flag and it will append.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the file in append mode as `'w'` mode will truncate the file each time., i.e

```
logfile = open(log, "a")
```

And you should use `with`:

```
with open(log, 'a') as logfile:
    logfile.write(sttime + error + '\n')
```

No need to close the file, this will happen automatically.

Note that if the exception is raised at `path = sys.argv[1]`, the timestamp might not be set when you try to log. It would be better to get the timestamp in the logging code.

Also, you should not use a bare `except` clause, but at least catch the exception and report it.

```
from datetime import datetime

except Exception, exc:
    sttime = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H:%M:%S - ')
    error = "ERROR! {}".format(exc)
    log = 'log.txt'
    with open(log, 'a') as logfile:
        logfile.write(sttime + error + '\n')
    raise
#    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: It's easy once you know how. I have addressed your immediate question, however, you should consider using the inbuilt [logging module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#module-logging)

Comment: ... and you should accept this answer if you found it to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

When you do file(log, 'W'). The file log will become empty. If you want to add something you should use a instead of w:

```
open(log, "a")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n 
        self.count = 0 
        self.log = open('log.txt', 'a')


    def write(self, message):
        self.count+=1
        if self.count<self.n:
            self.log.write("%s %s"% (time,message))
            self.log.flush()
import sys
sys.stdout= Logger()
```

time -- is time string formatted the way you want.

Now regular print function will write to file.